# Ionic 5 - Can't add component to other module than a specific page (tab) module

Tags: angular, module, components, ionic5

I can add component into a tab module page and works fine, but in order to use it on all tabs I want to move it into tabs module, but says that custom header(my new component) is not a known element.

I have tried to add it even to AppComponentModule but I always get the same error
[see files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMurf.png)